# In Ruby, what is the best way to hash two columns that share some values?

Tags: ruby, csv

The first column has some users, and the second column has their friends. Some of the users are present in both the columns, some are present in only one.

I want to hash the whole dataset to convert all the entries into number for easier processing. My code is this:

```
require 'csv'

udids = {}
unique_count = 1

output_csv = CSV.open("Processed.csv", "w")

CSV.foreach("Original.csv").with_index do |row, i|

  val = row[0]
  if udids[val.to_sym]
    row[0] = udids[val.to_sym]
  else
    udids[val.to_sym] = unique_count
    row[0] = unique_count
    unique_count += 1
  end

  val = row[1]
  if udids[val.to_sym]
    row[1] = udids[val.to_sym]
  else
    udids[val.to_sym] = unique_count
    row[1] = unique_count
    unique_count += 1
  end

  output_csv << row
end

output_csv.close
```

But this is producing what I think may not be the correct conversion. This is a sample output:

```
1   2
1   3
1   4
1   5
1   51
1   52
1   53
54  55
54  56
54  57
54  58
54  59
54  90
54  91
54  92
93  94
93  95
93  96
...
```

Here, the 2 columns don't share any single value, whereas that is highly unlikely to be the case. Plus, even if that's correct, I expected it to produce this as the corresponding sample output:

```
1   2
1   3
1   4
1   5
1   51
1   52
1   53
2   55
2   56
2   57
2   58
2   59
2   90
2   91
2   92
3   94
3   95
3   96
...
```

So, could anyone kindly help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the input you are feeding to this script so that those trying to help you can reproduce your results?  I justed tested your program on a small dataset and found not problems with it.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Its a 3 MB file. I'm not sure how I can share it here. Any suggestion?

Comment: You should reduce it to the smallest possible file that demonstrates the problem, and change the names to pseudonyms.  For example, maybe the first 200 lines of the file are sufficient to show the problem, and you could remove everything after that.  If the problem is still present, remove everything after the first 20 lines.  Continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to debug your program without seeing your input.  I am guessing that one issue with your code is that there is whitespace in the CSV file.  Since you are not stripping away the whitespace, the name " David" would be different from the name "David", and get a different ID.

Here is some code that works fine for me, and is also shorter:

```
require 'csv'

udids = {}
unique_count = Enumerator.new do |y|
  c = 0
  loop { y << (c += 1) }
end

output_csv = CSV.open('output.csv', 'w')

CSV.foreach('students.csv') do |row|
  row[0] = (udids[row[0].strip] ||= unique_count.next)
  row[1] = (udids[row[1].strip] ||= unique_count.next)
  output_csv << row
end

output_csv.close
```

Comment: Interesting use of Enumerator. At first I thought there was some funny business with `loop` that gets that to work, but I've just read that `<<` is aliased to `yield`. I'm still trying to make sense of the "yielder" object.

Answer (score 0):

**Unique ID Values**

To generate unique numeric IDs for a given set, I first define a hash as follows:

```
uniqueIdHash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = hash.size }
```

From the Ruby documentation, [`Hash.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-new) can take a block with the following meaning:

> If this hash is subsequently accessed by a key that doesn’t correspond
>   to a hash entry, the value returned depends on the style of new used
>   to create the hash.
>   . . .
>   If a block is specified, it will be called with the hash object and
>   the key, and should return the default value. It is the block’s
>   responsibility to store the value in the hash if required.

With the block suggested above, each time an unknown value is looked up in the hash, it will be added, along with a new unique number (the number of items in the hash before the addition).

Simply trying to translate values through the hash will then generate a unique ID if the value didn't previously exist, or return the previous ID if it now does exist.

**Processing the CSV**

In your example output of the processed CSV file, you maintain a priority for the first column. To obtain this, the data can be passed over twice, the first time looking up (and thus adding) the first column to the unique ID hash. The second pass would then assign unknown values from a second column subsequent ID numbers. The code is as follows:

```
require 'csv'

def convertCsvNamesToNums(inputFileName, outputFileName)
    # Create unique ID number hash
    # When unknown key is lookedup, it is added with new unique ID number
    # Produces a 0 based index
    nameHash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = hash.size }
    # Pass over the data once to give priority to user column for ID numbers
    CSV.open(inputFileName, "r") do |inputFile|
        inputFile.each do |name,|
            nameHash[name]  # Add name to unique ID number hash (if it doesn't already exist)
        end
    end
    # Convert input CSV with names to output CSV with ID numbers
    CSV.open(inputFileName, "r") do |inputFile|
        CSV.open(outputFileName, 'w') do |outputFile|
            inputFile.each do |row|
                # Parse names from input, map to ID numbers, and write to output
                outputFile << row.map{|name| nameHash[name]}
            end
        end
    end
end

convertCsvNamesToNums("Original.csv", "Processed.csv")
```